# os.walk is returning a generator object. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, os.walk

According to the documentation, `os.walk` returns a tuple with root, dirs and files in a given path. When I call `os.walk` I get the following:

```
>>> import os

>>> os.listdir('.')
['Makefile', 'Pipfile', 'setup.py', '.gitignore', 'README.rst', '.git', 'Pipfile.lock', '.idea', 'src']

>>> root, dir, files = os.walk('src')

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)

>>> print (os.walk('src')) generator object walk at 0x10b4ca0f8>
```

I just don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Code formatting and grammar tweaks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can convert it to a `list` if that's what you want:

```
list(os.walk('src'))
```

---

There is a little more to what generators are used for (probably best to just google "Python Generators" and read about it), but you can still `for-loop` over them:

```
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('src'):
    # Do stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did and it worked:

```
x = os.walk('/home')
for b in x:
    print(b)
```

This should give you the path names.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).